# What are the pros/cons of using apollo-link-ws for queries and mutations?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

The README says you can do either everything-over-ws or just subs over ws and queries/mutations over http.

https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws